# rvest error on form submission "`Form` doesn't contain a `action` attribute"

Tags: html, r, rvest

I am trying to send search requests with `rvest`, but I get always the same error. I have tried several ways included this solution: https://gist.github.com/ibombonato/11507d776d1042f80ca59cd31509afd3

My code is the following.

```
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://www.saferproducts.gov/PublicSearch'
cocorahs <- html_session(URL)

form.unfilled <- cocorahs %>% html_node("form") %>% html_form()

form.unfilled[["fields"]][[3]][["value"]] <- "input" ## This is the line which I think should be corrected


form.filled <- form.unfilled %>%
  set_values("searchParameter.AdvancedKeyword" = "amazon")


session1 <- session_submit(cocorahs, form.filled, submit = NULL)

# or 

session <- submit_form(cocorahs, form.filled)
```

But I get always the following error:

```
Error in `submission_build()`:
! `form` doesn't contain a `action` attribute
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I think the way is to edit the attributes of those buttons. Maybe has someone the answer to this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative method with `httr2`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr2)

data <- "https://www.saferproducts.gov/PublicSearch" %>% 
  request() %>%
  req_body_form(
    "searchParameter.Keyword" = "Amazon"
  ) %>% 
  req_perform() %>%  
  resp_body_html() 
  
tibble(
  title = data %>% 
    html_elements(".document-title") %>% 
    html_text2(), 
  report_title = data %>% 
    html_elements(".info") %>%  
    html_text2() %>%  
    str_remove_all("\r") %>% 
    str_squish()
)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    title                                                                 repor…¹
#>    <chr>                                                                 <chr>  
#>  1 Self balancing scooter was used off & on for three years. Consumer i… Incide…
#>  2 The consumer stated that when he opened one of the marshmallow roast… Incide…
#>  3 The consumer, 59, stated that he was welding with a brand new auto d… Incide…
#>  4 The consumer reported, that their hover soccer toy caught fire while… Incide…
#>  5 80 yr old male's electric hotplate was set between 1 and 2(of 5) bef… Incide…
#>  6 Amazon Recalls Amazon Basics Desk Chairs Due to Fall and Injury Haza… Recall…
#>  7 The Consumer reported to have been notified by email that the diarrh… Incide…
#>  8 consumer reported about light fixture attached to a photography umbr… Incide…
#>  9 Drive DeVilbiss Healthcare Recalls Adult Portable Bed Rails After Tw… Recall…
#> 10 MixBin Electronics Recalls iPhone Cases Due to Risk of Skin Irritati… Recall…
#> # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​report_title
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Nice solution. Tx!

Comment: A question, please. Is there a way to obtain more than 10 items in the result?

Comment: @RRuiz I looked into it and found no solution. Last resort must then be RSelenium